# Deriving the Euler-Lagrange Equation using the Gateaux Derivative

Tags: integration, euler-lagrange-equation, gateaux-derivative

Can anyone explain how the professor goes from line 4 to 5 of the derivation? In particular, how is:

$$\frac{\delta L}{\delta u}h'=-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\delta L}{\delta u'}h$$

The professor states that this can be derived from integration by parts but I still don't see how it's possible. I wrote out the integration by parts:

$$\int \frac{\delta L}{\delta u'}h' =\frac{\delta L}{\delta u'}h - \int \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\delta L}{\delta u'}h$$

How can I relate this to the above?

[Derivation Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSI7n.png)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! Please, don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources.

Answer (score 2):

It's just integration by part :

$$\int \left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial u'}h'\right)=\left[h\frac{\partial L}{\partial u'}\right]_{boundary}-\int \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial u'}h$$

But since $h$ has compact support, $h$ is $0$ on the boundary. Your equality follow.

Comment: Sorry, but why is $h$ $0$ on the boundary?

Comment: Well, it's true that in your document it's not precise. Normally, $h$ is a test function, i.e. $\mathcal C^\infty $ with compact support...

Comment: @user657324 You use $[ \cdot ]_{\text{boundary}}$ instead $|_a^b$. Is the because there is an analogue of integration by parts for multivariable functions?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding why $h$ is zero on the boundary: The slide doesn't mention, but in Calculus of Variations your problems usually have boundary conditions, otherwise the minimum often does not exist. That is, canonical problems are of the form
$$\min E(u) =  \int_0^1 L(u'(x), u(x), x) dx $$
$$\text{s.t. } \ u(0) = a, \ \ u(1) = b, \ u \in C^1([0, 1])$$
If $u^*$ is a local min, then we can say that $\phi(t) = E(u^* + th)$ has a local min at $0$ **for functions h which vanish at 0 and at 1**. If the $h$ doesn't vanish, then $u^* + th$ will not satisfy the boundary conditions, so we can't say that $\phi(t)$ has a local min at $0$.

So that's why we **pick** $h$ in the first place to be a function which vanishes at the boundary.